# Can a MBA 2014 output 2560x1080 at 60hz?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I've got a MacBook Air 2014 and I want to hook it up to a LG 29UM65 monitor.

The native resolution is 2560x1080. Can the MBA 2014 (Thunderbolt 1) output at that resolution at 60hz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bought a few of these panels last month on special.  They are great. I just tried to hook up my MBA11 2014 to the display and here are the options I got.

It doesn't look like it does 2560x1080

[image: MBA11]

Here is what I get when I try it on desktop mac [image: Hackintosh display]

Comment: That's pretty definitive! Thank you for taking the time to do this.